# Why flow type casting not working for string literal as expected

Tags: javascript, flowtype

For the below example why type casting is not working in Flowtypes? What should be an ideal way of doing it?

```
type typeA = {
  name: 'ben' | 'ken',
};
type typeB = {
  name: string,
};
const objA: typeA = { name: 'ben' };
const objB: typeB = objA;
```

It gives error

```
Cannot assign `objA` to `objB` because in property `name`: Either  string [1] is incompatible with  string literal `ben` [2]. Or  string [1] is incompatible with  string literal `ken` [3].
```

However, for typescript, it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Let's examine why your code is unsafe, [Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBKkIJQLxQN4CgpQHYEMC2EAXFAOQBGEWJUAPqQNaUkA0aAvgNxqzQ8BCSVBmz4iUAM7AATgEssAc1ac0AYwD2WSVDVkAVnGI8EyFCILFyTKMvWbg2vX0PgIA5Dv1QA9F6jqpUhAqwAA2IH44wCoAFhDiUBABalJQsYFQFCo4AK7iEAB0hWiqGlp42cCREAAqLm5QABQAbjghzpB8AJTETWoyACZIAHxCmFAtIfm4BIIARCGUsxzevoVTaglJKTLxWdny0fZpEOzF5ZXANXUNHl1cPthqAO4O+lOicwtYs5hAA):

```
type typeA = {
  name: 'ben' | 'ken',
};
type typeB = {
  name: string,
};
const objA: typeA = { name: 'ben' };
const objB: typeB = objA // correctly catches error here because...

const mutateTypeB = (val: typeB): void => {
   val.name = "len"; // ...no error is caught here
}

mutateTypeB(objB);
// now objA.name = "len"
```

Meaning you are able to mutate `objA` with a `name` property which does not match `typeA` but does match `typeB`. This is obviously unsafe.

Your error can be resolved in two ways:

1. Making name a `ReadOnly` field in `typeB` [Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBKkIJQLxQN4CgpQHYEMC2EAXFAOQBGEWJUAPqQNaUkA0aAvgNxqzQ8BCSVBigBqXAWIBnYACcAllgDmrTmgDGAeyzSoGsgCs4xHgmQps+IqQpUoqzduC6DfY+AgDkew13VadeACuwDjAEAAq7p5QABQAbjgANm6QfACUxHEacgAmSAB8QphQCYkAdOLQyABEiZTVHFAA9E1QEDIyGjJQajiBigAWTgPt0ArSEDg57GhoQSFhkakx3ulcLdgaAO7OhhWWgrX1mEA)

```
type typeA = {
  name: 'ben' | 'ken',
};
type typeB = {
  +name: string,
};
const objA: typeA = { name: 'ben' };
const objB: typeB = objA;

const mutateTypeB = (val: typeB): void => {
   val.name = "len"; // error caught here instead
}

mutateTypeB(objB);
// now objA.name = "len"
```

2. Adding `string` as part of the union in `typeA` [Flow Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBKkIJQLxQN4CgpQHYEMC2EAXFAOQBGEWJUAPqQNaXV0DOwATgJZYDmANGgC+AbjSxo4gEJJUGbPiJQ2XXgJFoAxgHssbKFrIArOMXEJkKeQWLkmUddt3B9RyafARpyA8eFA)

```
type typeA = {
  name: 'ben' | 'ken' | string,
};
type typeB = {
  name: string,
};
const objA: typeA = { name: 'ben' };
const objB: typeB = objA;
```

You can read more about this exact issue [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-covariant-read-only-properties-on-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a TypeScript flaw IMO and Flow does it right. Let's see why:

```
type A = {
  name: 'ben' | 'ken';
}

type B = {
  name: string;
}

const a: A = { name: 'ben' }
const b: B = a;

b.name = 'jen';

console.log({ a });
// this logs { a: { name: 'jen' } } <- see how a.name has an invalid value!
```

In JS when you write `b = a` means that `b` is an "alias" for `a` and in fact they're the same object.

So if you make changes to `b` then those changes also reflect on `a`, so if you're permitted to "lean" the `name` type definition from a given list of strings to a general string, you can go and change `a.name` with "illegal" or better unwanted values!